# Easy way to install AddressSanitizer enabled package?

Tags: package-management, debugging

I told a friend to install Ubuntu, but he is having problems with some software (libreoffice mostly). I would like to fix the problem, but he would need to install an AddressSanitizer enabled package to show a useful stacktrace.

Is there an easy way to install an AddressSanitizer enabled package from Ubuntu?

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html